# How can I customize the color of grid layout row

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

I have a Grid layout and I want to change the background color of a row in it, 
How can I do that?

Comment: If I get it right you wanna change the background of each item on the grid?

Comment: refer to [this](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/) link

Comment: no not each item but each row

Comment: cuz if i changed each item background  i wont get all the row filled with the background because you cant make the item fill the cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change each view background that you want as:
`yourView.setBackground(Color.blue);`